# Facebook like callback function not working in opera

Tags: facebook, callback, facebook-like

Do not work callback functions to this button. Opera Dragonfly for facebook shows this error:

> Unhandled Error: JSON.parse: Unescaped control char in string: "

in the file http://connect.facebook.net/ru_RU/all.js

Code pages standard:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/ru_RU/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
                   alert('ok'); 
                });
            }
        </script>
        <div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="150" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is going on with event.subscribe?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12060977/what-is-going-on-with-event-subscribe)